# Confusion about calculation involving E-L and Hamilton equations

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-equations

As you may know, the E-L equations are given by $\frac{d}{dt}
\left(
\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_j}
\right)
=
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j},\forall j\in\{
1,\ldots ,n
\}$, where $
\begin{matrix}
L:&\mathbb{R}^n&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\
&(v,x,t)&\mapsto&L(v,x,t)\\
\end{matrix}$

Now, if $\left|\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\right|\neq0$ we can locally solve $y_k=\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_j}
$ to yield $v_j=G_k(t,x,y)$. Then we define the hamiltonian $H=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_jv_j-L$.

So far, so good, now, the book I'm reading claims that
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_j}=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j},\frac{\partial H}{\partial y_j}=G_k
$$

From which the hamiltonian system follows. The funny thing is, I've have seen this computation many times before however now I can't figure out for the life of me, how $
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_j}=
-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j}
$

I just get, $
\displaystyle\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_k}=
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(
\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_k}v_j
+\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_k}y_j
\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j}
$(*)

And I don't know how to proceed. Any idea on how to show that
$
\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_k}v_j
+\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_k}y_j=0
$(which as I remember was the way to go to show (*))

Comment: $\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_j}=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j}$ follows from the definition of the Hamiltonian, and noting that the $x_j$ are absent from $\sum_{j=1}^ny_jv_j.$ I can't say I'm a fan of your book's notation. More usual: $H=\sum_i \dot{q}_i p_i-L.$

Comment: @Adrian Keister By definition $y_j$ depends on $x$, doesn't it?

Comment: Not in the usual formulation of Hamiltonian mechanics. Your $y_j$ correspond to momenta which, in the Hamiltonian schema, are viewed as independent from the generalized coordinates $x_j.$ Your $v_j$ are the generalized velocities. See the wiki here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics.

Comment: But by definition above, $y_k=\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_j}$ and $v_j=G_k(t,x,y)$ so both $y_k$ and $v_j$ depend on x as a variable. Btw, I agree with the notation issue, my physic professor prefered your(when I took the course last year).

Comment: Your argument does not show that the $y_k$ are dependent on the $x_j,$ and here's why: position and velocity are independent of each other. For a particle, pick any position, and you can choose any velocity you want. Conversely, pick any velocity, and you can choose any position you want. That the coordinates, velocities, and momenta in the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian formulations must obey certain laws doesn't change the fact that, *a priori*, you must view coordinates and momenta (in particular) as independent variables.

Comment: I understand your argument, but I can't wrap my map around that $y_k=\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_j}(t,x,v)$ So $y$ is the partial derivative  of a function that does depend on $x$! And therefore, how could it not depend on $x$?

Comment: In the wiki to which I linked before, in the section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#As_a_reformulation_of_Lagrangian_mechanics, in the paragraph beginning with the words, "Hamilton's equations consist of...", it says, "...because coordinates and momenta are independent variables with nearly symmetric roles." Unfortunately, I don't know of any better arguments for why the coordinates and momenta are independent than I have already given.

Comment: I will say this: if you're dealing with conservative forces, then when you consider $L=T-V,$ the $V$ is dependent only on coordinates and not on velocities. In that scenario, it is perhaps easier to see why the momenta are independent of the coordinates.

Comment: I guess you're right, I just don't think I fully understand it. Anyway, this discussion was very instructive and thank you very much for the references :)

Comment: You're welcome!